# 'Does not' with a plural sentence

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Should we use don't or doesn't in the below sentence and why?

"Knowing magic secrets doesn’t make you a magician"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"**Don't/doesn't**" work in the absolutely same way as "**do/does**".

If there is *one countable unit (or a gerund) or one uncountable unit* then "**doesn't**", if there are *more than one unit or a plural amount* then "**don't**":

- A horse and a revolver don't make you a cowboy.
- Having a lot of money doesn't make you happy.
- Money doesn't grow.
- Butterflies don't live a long a happy life.

However, in cases when *we render several units as a single unit, or as something abstract* we use "**doesn't**":

- A quill and ink doesn't write a story.
- His bread and butter doesn't bring in much money.

Comment: So it should be 'doesn't in the above example, considering 'magic secrets' as rendering several units as a single unit. Am i right?

Comment: No, "**Knowing magic secrets**" is a gerund thus "**doesn't**".